# Angularjs filtering if any input matches

Tags: angularjs

I have three input boxes of which I want to search from.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="firstName" />
<input type="text" ng-model="lastName" />
<input type="text" ng-model="occupation" />
```

The data is passed to the controller and my table is built.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="person in persons | filter: firstName 
        | filter: lastName | filter: Company">"
     <td>
      {{person.FirstName}}
     </td>
     <td>
      {{person.LastName}}
     </td>
     <td>
      {{person.Occupation}}
     </td>
```

I am having trouble filtering if ANY of the inputs generate a match. Currently, all inputs must match in order for a table item to be displayed.

For example, my table (FirstName LastName Occupation):

Bob Dylan Singer

Justin Timberlake Singer

George Lucas Filmmaker

My inputs: George Doe Singer

This should show all three from the list since George and Singer are matches.

Comment: Could you put up a JSFIDDLE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own custom filter which uses the OR condition instead of using the AND condition.

For example, add a reference to your new filter in the view:

**Html:**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in persons | filter: personFilter">"
    <td>
      {{person.FirstName}}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{person.LastName}}
     </td>
    <td>
      {{person.Occupation}}
    </td>
```

Then in the controller, (or seperate filter object), add the conditions required for the new filter

**Controller**

```
$scope.personFilter = function (person) {
    return ((person.firstName.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.firstName) > -1)  || (person.lastName.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.lastName) > -1) || (person.occupation.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.occupation) > -1));
}
```

Comment: i have done this previously, but this checks for exact string matches ( == not =). How can i still return results for substring/partial matches?

Comment: Sure, in your filter, you can use indexOf() function instead of =. I will update the answer in a second.

Comment: OK I have updated the condition to use indexOf and also toLowerCase

Comment: Just a note that indexOf is case sensitive. So you could handle any logic you want in the filter for that aswell.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to implement a custom filter, but I don't I don't like the fact that the entire array is passed to the filter function where it must return a new array containing only the elements you'd like to keep.  Also, I don't like having to specify the properties to filter by on `$scope` or hardcoding them within the custom filter.

You can use `filter:<predicate>` in `ng-repeat` and use function call which itself returns the predicate function used for the filtering like I've done in the snippet (`<tr ng-repeat="person in persons | filter:matchAnyProp(['firstName', 'lastName'])">`).  This way, I can specify the properties to filter by in the HTML or using an array of properties specified on `$scope`.  Also, I can reusable for matching different properties as well.

```js
var app = angular.module('MainApp', []);


app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  // An array to filter through
  $scope.persons = [ 
    { "firstName": "Milton", "lastName": "Erickson" },
    { "first": "Mattie", "lastName": "Thompson" },
    { "first": "Lura", "last": "Flores" },
    { "first": "Brent", "last": "Neal" },
    { "first": "Jean", "last": "Guerrero" },
    { "first": "Chester", "last": "Sims" },
    { "first": "Winnie", "last": "Potter" },
    { "firstName": "Richard", "lastName": "Obrien", "friend": "Fanny Arnold" },
    { "firstName": "Lena", "lastName": "Walsh", "friend": "Roger Lynch" },
    { "firstName": "Charlotte", "lastName": "Greer" },
    { "firstName": "Beulah", "lastName": "Logan", "friend": "Katie Singleton" },
    { "firstName": "Benjamin", "lastName": "Hodges" },
    { "first": "Bessie", "last": "Lloyd" },
    { "first": "Marie", "last": "Meyer" },
    { "firstName": "Rick", "lastName": "Sanchez" },
    { "first": "Lillie", "last": "Foster" },
    { "first": "Cynthia", "last": "Lowe" },
    { "name": "Grace", "last": "Sanchez" } 
  ];
  


    
    
  // Function which generates and returns a filter predicate
  // function that returns true or false if item contains 
  // any keys specified in "propsToMatch" argument
  $scope.matchAnyProp = function(propsToMatch){
    return (item) => Object.keys(item).reduce( (prev, curr, index, arry) => (propsToMatch.indexOf(curr) != -1) ? true : prev , false);
  };
}]);
```

```html
<table ng-app="MainApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl" class='table table-bordered table-striped'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First</th>
      <th>Last</th>
      <th>Friend</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in persons | filter:matchAnyProp(['firstName', 'lastName'])">
      <td>{{person.firstName}}</td>
      <td>{{person.lastName}}</td>
      <td>{{person.friend}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @forwardslashend Does the code it not run in this stackoverflow page in your browser?  What have you tried to get it working?  Heres a [plnkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/tYNlwooXtuynF75EIZDH/), I really can't make it any more straightforward than this.